# Remove duplicates from a Pandas dataframe taking into account lowercase letters and accents

Tags: python, strings, pandas, natural-language-processing

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

| code | town | district | suburb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | Benalmádena | Málaga | Arroyo de la Miel |
| 03 | Alicante | Jacarilla | Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla) |
| 04 | Cabrera d'Anoia | Barcelona | Cabrera D'Anoia |
| 07 | Lanjarón | Granada | Lanjaron |
| 08 | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Centro-Ifara |
| 09 | Córdoba | Córdoba | Cordoba |

For each row in the `suburb` column, if the value it contains is equal (in lower case and without accents) to `district` or `town` columns, it becomes NaN.

This is the code I am using:

```
df['suburb'] = np.where(
    ((df['suburb'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower() == df['town'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower())
    |  (df['suburb'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower() == df['district'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower())
    ),
    np.nan, df['suburb']) 
df
```

Example result:

| code | town | district | suburb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | Benalmádena | Málaga | Arroyo de la Miel |
| 03 | Alicante | Jacarilla | Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla) |
| 04 | Cabrera d'Anoia | Barcelona | NaN |
| 07 | Lanjarón | Granada | NaN |
| 08 | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Centro-Ifara |
| 09 | Córdoba | Córdoba | NaN |

I would like to reduce the amount of code, as I am sure it can be made shorter with the same performance.

Comment: can't you factor out the repeated operations?  The str processing on that column is repeated several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could use a function:

```
def accent_free(s: str):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8').lower()
```

Of course, you want this vectorized for numpy, so:

```
accent_free = np.vectorize(accent_free)
```

Now, you just need to use this function:

```
df['suburb'] = np.where(
    ((accent_free(df['suburb']) == accent_free(df['town'])) |
     (accent_free(df['suburb']) == accent_free(df['district']))
    ),
    np.nan, df['suburb'])
```

Complete working example:

```
import unicodedata
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def accent_free(s: str):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8').lower()

accent_free = np.vectorize(accent_free)

data = [
    ["02", "Benalmádena", "Málaga", "Arroyo de la Miel"],
    ["03", "Alicante", "Jacarilla", "Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla)"],
    ["04", "Cabrera d'Anoia", "Barcelona", "Cabrera D'Anoia"],
    ["07", "Lanjarón", "Granada", "Lanjaron"],
    ["08", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Centro-Ifara"],
    ["09", "Córdoba", "Córdoba", "Cordoba"],
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["code", "town", "district", "suburb"])
df['suburb'] = np.where(
    ((accent_free(df['suburb']) == accent_free(df['town'])) |
     (accent_free(df['suburb']) == accent_free(df['district']))
    ),
    np.nan, df['suburb']) 

print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: I get this error:
```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'accent_free' referenced before assignment```

Comment: If I remove the command ```accent_free = np.vectorize(accent_free)```, I get this other error:
```TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not Series```

Comment: I've added a MCVE.  Hope that helps.

Comment: continues the same error: ```accent_free = np.vectorize(accent_free)```

```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'accent_free' referenced before assignment```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to put that statement inside another function, instead of **at the global context** where `accent_free` is defined.  The statement is redefining the function, and **must only be done once**.  You don’t want to revectorize an already vectorized function, so you do not want the statement executed every function call!  Note: I’m using CPython, not IronPython or some other snake.  Instead of using the same name, you could assign to a different name, and use the new name in your query.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks a lot!